# What is the $\lim_{n \to \infty} P^n$?

Tags: matrices, limits

Let $$P = \begin{pmatrix}            1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\ 
                                 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\ 
                                 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

What is the $\lim_{n \to \infty}  P^n$?

Is it
$$\begin{pmatrix}            1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                 2/3 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 \\ 
                                 1/3 & 0 & 0 & 2/3 \\ 
                                 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

?

Comment: It's worth doing a few example computations, $P^2$,$P^3$, etc.

Comment: Is this the answer (please see my edit above) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general expression for $P^n$ ($n>2$) is given by

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \dfrac{2}{3}\cdot \dfrac{4^{\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil}-1}{4^{\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil}} & \dfrac{(1+(-1)^n)}{2^{n+1}} & \dfrac{(1-(-1)^n)}{2^{n+1}} & \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{4^{\lceil\frac{n-1}{2}\rceil}-1}{4^{\lceil \frac{n-1}{2}\rceil}} \\ \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{4^{\lceil\frac{n-1}{2}\rceil}-1}{4^{\lceil \frac{n-1}{2}\rceil}} & \dfrac{(1-(-1)^n)}{2^{n+1}} & \dfrac{(1+(-1)^n)}{2^{n+1}} & \dfrac{2}{3}\cdot \dfrac{4^{\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil}-1}{4^{\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil}} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right).$$

It's easy to see that the central terms go to zero. As $n\to\infty$, $\dfrac{4^{\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil}-1}{4^{\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil}}$ goes to $1$ and likewise $\dfrac{4^{\lceil\frac{n-1}{2}\rceil}-1}{4^{\lceil \frac{n-1}{2}\rceil}}$ goes to $1$. Hence:

$$\lim_n P^n = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right).$$